# Simple Question About Adding Data To Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using an mvc application and in _Layout.cshtml page I have some javascript I wanna pass it a value of

```
 System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["anID"].ToString()
```

here

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var _gaq = _gaq || [];
            _gaq.push(['_setAccount',PASS THAT HERE!]);
```

How do I do this? I am not sure how to pass data to javascript??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try like this:

```
<% 
    var value = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["anID"].ToString();
%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || []; 
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', <%= value %>]);
</script>
```

or with the Razor view engine:

```
@{ 
    var value = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["anID"].ToString();
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || []; 
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', @value]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In situations where you have more javascript than that, and are keeping it in a separate file from the view, you can also do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _anId = @System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["anID"].ToString();
    var _somethingElseNeededInJsFile = @Model.SomethingNeeded;
</script>
```

Then in the separate javascript file, you can reference the variables easily.

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', _anId]);

alert('You needed this:  ' + _somethingElseNeededInJsFile);
```